# Reverse Order of data insertion in AFTER INSERT Triggers SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have 2 tables. The CREATE statements are provided below.

```
create table tab1(id int identity, val varchar(20))
create table tab2(id int identity, val varchar(20))
```

I also have an AFTER INSERT Trigger in table 1:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[insertTab2] on [dbo].[tab1]
for insert 
as 
begin
insert into tab2(val)
select val from inserted
end
```

I then perform a single multiple row insert statement in Table 1:

```
insert into tab1 values('a'),('b'),('c')
```

This by logic, now triggers an insertion in table 2.

The order of insertion in table1 was : a,b,c

When I perform select on table 1. It is : a,b,c

When I perform select on table 2. It is : c,b,a

Why is the data inserted in reverse order in table 2?
What needs to be done to insert them in the same order as in table 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `ORDER BY`clause to the trigger:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[insertTab2] ON [dbo].[tab1]
FOR INSERT
AS 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tab2 (val)
    SELECT val FROM inserted ORDER BY id
  END
```

If you don't specify `order by`the ordering of a query result will be non-predictable; it might be in the desired order or it might not.

Comment: Thanks, any specific reasons for such non- predictable behavior.

Comment: If you don't force a specific order it's up to the query planner to use whatever order is most efficient for the query to execute. It might be using indices, or physical order or something else.